# How to get Django integrate form fields form outside of the form class?

Tags: django

i have a question concerning the form api in django. I've created a regular form class but don't want to rewrite a html select field with hundreds of options into the form class. instead I want to put it directly into the template.

How do i integrate the information of the request (eg. request.POST.get('Country')) from the select field into my regular validation process and make it accessible as one validated set of data like form.cleaned_data ?

Hope i could make myself clear...

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you need to validate the select field then you probably need to have its contents included programmatically somewhere. Why not do that and then render the field in the template so that the form class taks care of validation ? Basically, create a tuple of field options and add a field to the form class.

Comment: @AshrayBaruah thaks for your comment! the select field is a list of countries copied from a different project and needs to be integrated into the regular form i've created via the form api. It would be an overkill for me to rewrite the whole thing into the form class... or to write a script which is doing that

Comment: What does "rewrite it into the form class" mean? Forms are classes, you can subclass them and add fields as necessary. Why will that not work for you?

Comment: @DanielRoseman because writing it in this kind of widgets makes a lot of extra work?!

Comment: Why? How? You've given no evidence that this is the case. And balance that against the definite extra work that you will have to do to make your form validation right.